# AngularJS overlaps http.get results and limits them to 10 per page

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-controller

This happens to be my first angularJS application that fetches data from newsapi and displays all the result in an infinite scrolling pattern.
I am getting data but not as expected, the new results overlap the previous ones and limits to 10 per page.

please advice if i am doing something wrong.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">

<script 
 src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js">
</script>

<body>
<div class="w3-container" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<p>Today's News:</p>
<div class="w3-card-4" style="width:100px margin:20px" ng-repeat="x in 
source">
<img src="{{x.urlToImage}}" style="width:100%">
<div class="w3-container w3-center">
<h2><a href="{{x.url}}" target="_blank">{{x.title}}</a></h2>
</div>
</div><br><br>
</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
var websites = ["the-times-of-india", "google-news", "bbc-news", "mirror", 
"reuters", "the-hindu", "the-new-york-times", "the-wall-street-journal"];
for(var i=0; i<websites.length;i++){
$http.get("https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=" +websites[i] 
+"&apiKey=f483fa2a3f714981afbee1a1996545b4")
.then(function(response) {
$scope.source = response.data.articles;
});
}
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are overwriting $scope.source in each loop over the sources. If you need to get all sources you can push it to an array of sources:

```
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  var websites = ["the-times-of-india", "google-news", "bbc-news", "mirror", 
    "reuters", "the-hindu", "the-new-york-times", "the-wall-street-journal"];
  $scope.sources=[];
  for(var i=0; i<websites.length;i++){
    $http.get("https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=" +websites[i] 
    +"&apiKey=f483fa2a3f714981afbee1a1996545b4")
    .then(function(response) {
      $scope.sources.push(response.data.articles);
    });
  }
})
```

Then, you can use the $scope.sources and iterate over each source.

If you need all articles merged in one array, you can use the concat() method for arrays:

```
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  var websites = ["the-times-of-india", "google-news", "bbc-news", "mirror", 
    "reuters", "the-hindu", "the-new-york-times", "the-wall-street-journal"];
  $scope.source=[];
  for(var i=0; i<websites.length;i++){
    $http.get("https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=" +websites[i] 
    +"&apiKey=f483fa2a3f714981afbee1a1996545b4")
    .then(function(response) {
      if (response.data.articles){
         $scope.source.concat(response.data.articles);
      }
    });
  }
})
```

Now you have a $scope.source with all articles merged into one array.

Comment: Thanks a lot Igor, the push method worked to my needs. Although, the concat method returned an empty array